# Comparing records in a data set represented as a two level list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a data matrix I wanted to compare data inside it with itself.
it's an easy task

First my Data looks like this:

```
{{"C(CCH)2        ", "singlet   ", "DFT       ", 
  "Triplet orbs", -191.426, 
  "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-s.out"}, {"C(CCH)2        ", "triplet   ", 
  "DFT       ", "Triplet orbs", -191.435, 
  "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-t.out"}}
```

(I dunno how to get rid of the tab spaces)

I just put the below code in a loop

```
 Do[If[data[[i, 1]] == data[[j, 1]] And data[[i, 2]] != 
  data[[j, 2]] And data[[i, 3]] == data[[j, 3]] And data[[i, 4]] == 
  data[[j, 4]], {excel[[i, 1]] = data[[i, 1]], 
  excel[[i, 2]] = data[[i, 5] - data[[j, 5]]]}], {i,1,Lenghth[data[[i,1]]},{j,1,Lenghth[data[[i,1]]}]
```

I just seem not to remember how I was used to stop it from comparing itself to itself.
And by the way how can I speed up the loops?

Update:

> thanks to m_goldberg
>   Truth be said the data comes from reading a file which is produced with bash script which reads results from a big set of calculations ran on a cluster (which is why I was forced to use Bash instead of mathematica) and these calculations tend to have so many errors which would reflect on the bash script output file so a bigger set would look like this (with the help of triming idea from m_goldberg).

```
{{"C(CCH)2", "singlet", "CC", "TO", "", 1.3171, -191.127, 
  "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-CC-s.out"}, {"C(CCH)2", "singlet", "DFT", "TO",
   "", 1.10879, -191.426, "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-s.out"}, {"C(CCH)2", 
  "triplet", "DFT", "TO", "", 2.23599, -191.435, 
  "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-t.out"}, {"C(NH2)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", 
  "", 2.00976, -149.832, "3-1/C-NH2-2/C-NH2-2-t.out"}, {"C(NMe2)2", 
  "triplet", "DFT", "TO", "", "ERROR", "", "NOT OPTIMIZED", "", 
  "3-1/C-NMe2-2/C-NMe2-2-t.out"}, {"C(SH)2", "singlet", "CC", "TO", 
  "", "ERROR", "", "input issue or ?", 
  "3-1/C-SH-2/C-SH-2-CC-s.out"}, {"C(SH)2", "singlet", "DFT", "TO", 
  "", 6.*10^-6, -835.262, "3-1/C-SH-2/C-SH-2-s.out"}, {"C(SH)2", 
  "triplet", "DFT", "TO", "", 2.0341, -835.191, 
  "3-1/C-SH-2/C-SH-2-t.out"}}
```

Comment: Change the 1 in the j definining from to i+1 {i,1,Lenghth[data[[i,1]]},{j,i+1,Lenghth[data[[i,1]]}]

Comment: what about the end, j wouldn't exist and I would be running an extra cycle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With only two records in your example data set, it is hard for me to write code that will handle all the variations that might occur in a real data set, but perhaps this answer will give you some ideas about how approach your task.

```
raw = 
  {{"C(CCH)2        ", "singlet   ", "DFT       ", "Triplet orbs", -191.426, 
    "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-s.out"}, 
   {"C(CCH)2        ", "triplet   ", "DFT       ", "Triplet orbs", -191.435, 
    "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-t.out"}};
```

This will trim the spaces both ends of the strings.

```
data = Map[If[Head[#] === String, StringTrim[#], #] &, raw, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{"C(CCH)2", "singlet", "DFT", "Triplet orbs", -191.426, 
>   "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-s.out"}, 
>  {"C(CCH)2", "triplet", "DFT", "Triplet orbs", -191.435, 
>   "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-t.out"}}
> ```

This will group the cleaned-up data according to your criteria.

```
sets = Gather[data, 
         #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] && #1[[2]] != #2[[2]] && 
         #1[[3]] == #2[[3]] && #1[[4]] == #2[[4]] &]
```

> ```
> {{"C(CCH)2", "singlet", "DFT", "Triplet orbs", -191.426, 
>   "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-s.out"}, 
>  {"C(CCH)2", "triplet", "DFT", "Triplet orbs", -191.435, 
>   "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-t.out"}}
> ```

As you can see the two elements belong to same data group, so the gathering has essentially done nothing. But surely that won't be the case for real data.

This will make an extraction that is not quite what you specified. The function I apply to column 5 is `List`, but you can apply any function you want.

```
excel = {#[[1, 1]], List @@ #[[All, 5]]} & /@ sets
```

> ```
> {{"C(CCH)2", {-191.426, -191.435}}}
> ```

I think you must post a more realistic data set to get a really good answer.

#### Update

With the new data example posted by the OP, I can take the data exploitation further, but I still can't give a truly general answer. The OP's data, like most experimental data, has very localized properties that require an idiomatic approach.

```
data = 
  {{"C(CCH)2", "singlet", "CC", "TO", "", 1.3171, -191.127, "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-CC-s.out"}, 
   {"C(CCH)2", "singlet", "DFT", "TO", "", 1.10879, -191.426, "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-s.out"}, 
   {"C(CCH)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", "", 2.23599, -191.435, "3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-t.out"}, 
   {"C(NH2)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", "", 2.00976, -149.832, "3-1/C-NH2-2/C-NH2-2-t.out"}, 
   {"C(NMe2)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", "", "ERROR", "", "NOT OPTIMIZED", "", "3-1/C-NMe2-2/C-NMe2-2-t.out"}, 
   {"C(SH)2", "singlet", "CC", "TO", "", "ERROR", "", "input issue or ?", "3-1/C-SH-2/C-SH-2-CC-s.out"}, 
   {"C(SH)2", "singlet", "DFT", "TO", "", 6.*10^-6, -835.262, "3-1/C-SH-2/C-SH-2-s.out"}, 
   {"C(SH)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", "", 2.0341, -835.191, "3-1/C-SH-2/C-SH-2-t.out"}};
```

Extract the relevant fields

```
 relevant = data[[All, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7}]]
```

> ```
> {{"C(CCH)2", "singlet", "CC", "TO", 1.3171, -191.127}, 
>  {"C(CCH)2", "singlet", "DFT", "TO", 1.10879, -191.426}, 
>  {"C(CCH)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", 2.23599, -191.435}, 
>  {"C(NH2)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", 2.00976, -149.832}, 
>  {"C(NMe2)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", "ERROR", ""}, 
>  {"C(SH)2", "singlet", "CC", "TO", "ERROR", ""}, 
>  {"C(SH)2", "singlet", "DFT", "TO", 6.*10^-6, -835.262}, 
>  {"C(SH)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", 2.0341, -835.191}}
> ```

Remove error records

```
 noerr = If[NumberQ[#[[5]]], #, Nothing] & /@ relevant
```

> ```
> {{"C(CCH)2", "singlet", "CC", "TO", 1.3171, -191.127}, 
>  {"C(CCH)2", "singlet", "DFT", "TO", 1.10879, -191.426}, 
>  {"C(CCH)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", 2.23599, -191.435}, 
>  {"C(NH2)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", 2.00976, -149.832}, 
>  {"C(SH)2", "singlet", "DFT", "TO", 6.*10^-6, -835.262}, 
>  {"C(SH)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", 2.0341, -835.191}}
> ```

Group according to the OP's criteria

```
sets = 
  Gather[noerr, 
         #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] && #1[[2]] != #2[[2]] && 
         #1[[3]] == #2[[3]] && #1[[4]] == #2[[4]] &]
```

> ```
> {{{"C(CCH)2", "singlet", "CC", "TO", 1.3171, -191.127}}, 
>  {{"C(CCH)2", "singlet", "DFT", "TO", 1.10879, -191.426}, 
>   {"C(CCH)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", 2.23599, -191.435}}, 
>  {{"C(NH2)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", 2.00976, -149.832}}, 
>  {{"C(SH)2", "singlet", "DFT", "TO", 6.*10^-6, -835.262}, 
>   {"C(SH)2", "triplet", "DFT", "TO", 2.0341, -835.191}}}
> ```

Extract (what I guess to be) the wanted information

```
f[x_] := x
f[x_, y__] := (x - Plus @ y)
excel = {#[[1, 1]], f @@ #[[All, 5]]} & /@ sets
```

> ```
> {{"C(CCH)2", 1.3171}, 
>  {"C(CCH)2", -1.1272}, 
>  {"C(NH2)2", 2.00976}, 
>  {"C(SH)2", -2.03409}}
> ```

Comment: I updated my Post you response gave me valuable ideas thanks